# How to centre list-items in a column

Tags: html, css, wordpress, center, html-lists

I am trying to centre page numbers at the bottom of this test blog...

http://jocelynwarner.com/test/

in the centre between the previous and next buttons however I cannot think how to do it, I tried a few different tutorials but they didn't really seem to help with this.

Any hints on how to make them sit centrally in the left column (the width of the blog content - sidebar) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pablo has it right. This is a good case where using `display:inline-block` helps simplify things. By the way, here is a good post about the advantages and disadvantages of using it when you want a horizontal list:
[CSS display: inline-Block: Why It Rocks, And Why It Sucks](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Also, this is kind of unrelated, but according to your description you want the pagination div to be the same size of the content column, right? in this case, you should give the pagination class a `width` of `548px`, the same as your posts class, no?

Comment: Great article, I am unclear from Pablo's post what this has to do with anything but it was a good article.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Pablo's answer in order to properly support `inline-block` on all browsers:

```
.pagination .third {
    /* Supports Firefox < 3.0, note
       that it is not 1:1 identical
       to inline-block but it is
       usually a good substitute */
    display: -moz-inline-box;

    /* Standards support */
    display: inline-block;

    /* IE 6 & 7 do not support
       inline-block for block-
       level elements; fortunately
       inline + hasLayout is exactly
       the same as inline-block in
       these browsers */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use conditional css?

Comment: @unknowndomain, specifically for the IE 6/7 styles? (Firefox of course does not support conditional comments.) It depends. Including additional styles or stylesheets in conditional comments increases load time. But I included comments to indicate what the styles are for, how you implement them is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I bother and copy the pagination Div

```
<div class="pagination">
 <div class="third"></div>
 <div class="third">
  <ul class="page-numbers page-bright current-page-cyan behind-dark fill-gradient shape-  round">
   <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
   <li><a href="http://jocelynwarner.com/test/page/2/" class="page-numbers">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://jocelynwarner.com/test/page/3/" class="page-numbers">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://jocelynwarner.com/test/page/4/" class="page-numbers">4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="third">
  <a href="http://jocelynwarner.com/test/page/2/">
   <p class="next">Next »</p>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the new Style that will make it Centered

```
    .pagination {
      border-top:1px dotted;
      float:left;
      font-size:12px;
      margin-top:10px;
      padding-top:10px;
      text-align:center;
      width:708px;
    }
    .pagination .third {
      display:inline-block;
    }
    ul.page-numbers {
      /*Clear all styles for this*/
    }
```

I recommend Reading the CSS Reference and tutorials at [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Comment: I tried wat your saying but I don't think I got my meaning across because I am unclear as to how your suggested changes actually make the page numbers centralised in the main colum which is what I was struggling with, perhaps I am missing something but I initally read your code and was unsure so I decided just to put it in un-edited and there is no significant changes.

Thanks for your help perhaps you can tell me what I missed?